# How do I add jQuery back button in Dreamweaver?

Tags: jquery, cordova, dreamweaver

I'm in the process of learning jQuery and the tutorial I'm following uses Dreamweaver CS5.5 and the Phonegap sample app. Each view in the sample app has a Back button but the jQuery mobile sample app in Dreamweaver CS6 doesn't have any back buttons so I'm trying to figure out how to add them manually. I can do it using Go back but how can I do it using one of the jQuery buttons?

I've tried `<button data-rel="back" data-theme="e">Button</button>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: That is explained in the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first refer to the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

It should be as simple as `<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>`

However it isn't suggested to use `#` due to the fact that it will be useless in C-grade browsers, as noted in documentation.